# Master page no HTML

Tags: html, html5

Bom dia! 
Estou tentando fazer uma Master Page no HTML 5. 
Criei uma págima HTML chamada master.html com toda estrutura de menus que quero. 
Chamo essa página da seguinte maneira na minha página index.php e funciona:

```
<html>
    <body>        
        <div id="new-header">
            <script>
                $("#new-header").load("page/master.html");
            </script>
        </div>

        <div>Index</div>     

    </body>
</html>
```

Quando chamo essa mesma estrutura em outra página, profile.html por exemplo, a estrutura da master não funciona !
O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Comment: olha cara sinceramente era pra dar certo o load nessa div, edita e coloca o caminho da index.php e de onde está a master.html, aparentemente é o caminho que está incorreto, senão vejo outra solução.

Comment: gostaria de saber como será o inserido o novo conteudo na pagina herdada ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu erro ocorre devido a falta da referência do Jquery.

Basta você incluir a referência que pode ser feito via Cdn,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

ou via download que pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://jquery.com/download/).

Veja esse exemplo que fiz.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="new-header">

    </div>

    <div>Index</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
             $("#new-header").load("page/master.html");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Todas as páginas que você inserir o código de inserção do "page/master.html" deverá conter o Jquery. Coloque o seguinte código dentro da tag head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Ou baixe o jquery e mude o src para o seu local.

Caso não queira colocar o código em toda página que for fazer a inserção, pode trocar o seu script de inserção do "page/master.html" por um include em php:

```
<?php include("page/master.html") ?>
```

Ou um iframe em html:

```
<iframe src="page/master.html"></iframe>
```